# Yii 2 rest service url management

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2

I just want to offer a Rest api for my Yii 2 application.
I saw the guide and in this default case everything clear.

But I want some "tricky" path and url things and I don't know how to achieve them.

First thing, my api controllers are outside my web root, like this:
- "Complete Application folder"
---- "Api"
-------- "controllers"
---- "Web root"
-------- "assets"
-------- "components"
-------- "config"
-------- "..."

Second thing is, I want my urls under the prefix "Api", like this:
http://www.myapp.de/Api/Model

Can someone help me to achieve this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve this if you chooses this kind of folder structure

if you choose **Yii 2 advanced application template**

you have to create an application like frontend or backend, what you have to do is create another directory call 'api' same as backend or frontend, and it'll contain folder structure same as backend|frontend except assets, views, widgets etc. (v1 for versions)

```
api

-config
-modules
--v1
---controllers
---models
-runtime
-tests
-web

backend
common
console
environments
frontend
```

---

if you choose **Yii 2 basic application template** to develop rest api, it's posible. create module call 'api' and create a sub directory call 'v1' as sub-module. (v1 for versions)
[(Yii doc -A module may consist of sub-modules.)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html)[(GiovanniDerks - backend sub-modules)](http://www.slideshare.net/GiovanniDerks/yii-backend-submodules-28238101)

```
-modules
--api
---v1
----controllers
----models
```

There is an advantage of using one of these folder structure, because you don't have to worry about route much.

```
https://domain.com/api/v1/products
```

Here is good example/project for RESTful API with advance template

[Setup RESTful API in Yii2(budiirawan)](https://github.com/deerawan/yii2-advanced-api)

Here is an ebook for REST API standards

[REST API Desing Rulebook](http://precious.hu/b/Oreilly.REST.API.Design.Rulebook.Oct.2011.pdf)